# TextFieldAutoSize and textWidth in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to draw a background to a text field in AS3.

I have a TextField with an embedded font and using autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT.  I assign the text to the TextField then call try to draw a roundedRect using the textWidth of the TextField.  The text field width is always smaller than the actual text width.

Is there another way to get the actual textwidth?  I did a few quick google searched but I haven't found anything.

Code:

```
var tfProgramName:TextField = TextUtil.createTextField(true,"Arial",20,true);
tfProgramName.width = 100;
tfProgramName.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tfProgramName.x = 5;
tfProgramName.y = 5;
addChild(tfProgramName);

tfProgramName.text = _program.title;
background.graphics.clear();
background.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000,0.75);
background.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,tfProgramName.textWidth+10,this.height+10,5,5);
background.graphics.endFill();
```

textWidth in my case is something like 373, but it should be closer to 400.  It's definitely close, but it doesn't seem to take into account the font or font size.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's tough to discern where exactly you're going wrong.

Comment: Sorry guys, there is no answer.  There is no issue related to the text width.  The parent MovieClip was being scaled down, but since my font wasn't actually embedding it was scaling down my background but not my text.  So I thought it was not finding the correct width.  Once I solved the embed issue and scaling issues, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't promise it will be any better, but take a look at [TextLineMetrics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html) It gives you more information than anything else, so this is probably your best bet.

Comment: This ends up giving me the same number as field.textWidth

Answer (score 0):

What you could try to do is use the return values of TextField's getCharBoundaries() or getCharIndexAtPoint(). The TextField's textWidth property always seems to be off by a couple of pixels - it will return some width *smaller* than the actual width of your text. LineMetrics may also help, haven't used it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

The TextField Class not only has the attribute .width, but also .textWidth, which will return the real TextWidth. In order to get the starting point of the TextField you also need the starting x Position, which you can get with the TextLineMetrics, just like Tyler wrote:

```
var lineMetrics : TextLineMetrics = textField.getLineMetrics(0);
var startX : Number = lineMetrics.x;
```

and width will be either:

```
lineMetrics.width;
```

or

```
textField.textWidth;
```